# Подсчет записей в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Как посчитать количество записей из дополнительной таблицы?

Есть запрос

```
$get = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        values_to_products 
        LEFT JOIN values ON (value_id = vtp_value_id) 
    WHERE 
        vtp_products_id IN (".implode(',', $pIds).") 
        ".((!empty($ids)) ? " AND vtp_value_id IN (".implode(',', $ids).") " : "")." 
    ORDER BY 
        value_id
");
```

Мне нужно посчитать сколько **products_id** из другой таблицы **products** у которых **vtp_value_id = products_value_id**
и добавить в результат выборки этого запроса как **products_count**

Я пробовал так.
Если делать дополнительно "count(products_id) as products_count", и добавить "GROUP BY vtp_value_id", то считает(!), но результат выборки не тот выходит какой нужен.

Вернуть должно все из таблиц, где могут повторяться vtp_value_id.

Как тут быть? Дополнительный запрос не пойдет, так как итак при в этой части кода делается три запроса.

Comment: Не [ЭТО](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40f83/1) случайно хотели? Или я направление выборки перепутал?

Лучше там же (на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)) укажите структуру ваших таблиц и выборку (что хотите получить).

Проще будет)

Comment: не так.
тот запрос который я привел выше возвращает все как нужно. Просто дополнительно нужно считать связь vtp_value_id = products_value_id с таблицей products, которую не знаю как в этот запрос приткнуть.
Вот пример что должно возвращать
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2a9/3

Comment: Тогда, может быть, [ЭТО](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/189a2/10)?

К вашему запросу добавил колонку с общим количеством по данному VALUE.

Че-то не нравится мне это... Не знаю как при большом количестве данных поведет себя join + подсчет числа с группировкой. Может быть стоит для каждого VALUE получать количество отдельно? Может быть даже быстрее будет. Если первый вариант начнет тормозить - смотрите в сторону второго, либо альтернативных.

И еще - повторно - случайно наткнулся. Чтобы мне оповещение пришло - скопируйте мой ник, добавьте собаку перед ним (@drop_off) - тогда знать буду, что написали

Comment: @BOPOH , большое спасибо, получилось теперь!

Если будет тормозить сильно, то отдельно буду считать, а потом сливать в общий массив. Хотя там не много всего будет, за исключением только products. Я пока с отладкой не очень понимаю в запросас, да и индексах так же... Буду разбираться.

зы. добавьте комментарий свой как ответ, я выберу его. хочется + поставить, а можно только через ответ.
Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @drop_off, будем считать, что вы его уже поставили) Я не уверен, что  это подходящее решение, поэтому в комментариях и пишу.

Если эта выборка будет часто производиться, то может быть стоит кэшировать эту сумму. Например, при добавлении/удалении записи увеличивать общую сумму в какой-нить таблице. А при построении выборки просто join`им эту таблицу и получаем нужные значения.

Тем более, сами написали, что та самая таблица products может содержать много данных. Хотя, может быть, подсчет количества на индексах и быстро выполняется...

Comment: ))

@BOPOH, кэшировать не вариант. там нужно моментально вести подсчет в зависимости от условий выборки. Т.е. одинаковый результат может возвращать 1-2 раза из 10 одному юзеру. Все остальные результаты будут разные.

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/189a2/10)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
drop table if exists `values`;
create table `values` (
  `value_id` int(10) null default null,
  `value_name` varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists `values_to_products`;
create table `values_to_products` (
  `vtp_products_id` int(10) null default null,
  `vtp_value_id` int(10) null default null
);

drop table if exists `products`;
create table `products` (
  `products_id` int(10) null default null,
  `products_value_id` int(10) null default null

);

insert into `values` (`value_id`, `value_name`) values
  (1,'name 1'), (2, 'name 2'), (3, 'name 3'), (4, 'name 4');

insert into `values_to_products` (`vtp_products_id`, `vtp_value_id`) values
  (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1), (1, 2);

insert into `products` values
  (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  vp.*, v.*, count(p.products_id)
FROM
  values_to_products AS vp

LEFT JOIN `values` AS v ON (v.value_id = vp.vtp_value_id)
LEFT JOIN `products` AS p ON (p.products_value_id = vp.vtp_value_id)

WHERE 
  vp.vtp_products_id IN (1,2,3,4) AND 
  vp.vtp_value_id IN (1,2,3,4,1) 
GROUP BY vp.vtp_value_id, vp.vtp_products_id
ORDER BY 
  v.value_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/189a2/10/0)**:

```
| vtp_products_id | vtp_value_id | value_id | value_name | count(p.products_id) |
|-----------------|--------------|----------|------------|----------------------|
|               1 |            1 |        1 |     name 1 |                    3 |
|               2 |            1 |        1 |     name 1 |                    3 |
|               3 |            2 |        2 |     name 2 |                    2 |
|               1 |            2 |        2 |     name 2 |                    2 |
|               4 |            3 |        3 |     name 3 |                    0 |
```